# Change magento theme/storeview based on referring URL?

Tags: magento

What’s the best way to change the theme or store view of a site based on the referring URL?

I have the following scenario:

SiteA.com with custom theme
SiteB.com sends traffic to SiteA.com

When that traffic arrives, I’d like it to have a different header, footer and some css overrides.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found this page, [Change Store View by Referrer URL](http://www.e-commercewebdesign.co.uk/blog/magento-tips/change-store-view-by-referer-url.php), I believe this may solve my problem.

Comment: The link provided no longer works.  This is why it's important to list the answer out.

Answer (score -1):

Main **index.php** file is best place to do this. Examine the referring url and change params passed to Mage::run method on line 88;

```
Mage::run($mageRunCode, $mageRunType);
```

Comment: There isn't a way to use a theme exception? It seems like user agent is the only method for overriding a theme there. Would that be a place to look at extending?

Comment: For siteA.com you can create multiple store view with different themes and when traffic arrives to siteA.com through siteB.com you can load store and it's view accordingly.

Comment: Never ever touch the index.php!!! No one will know or remeber later if you work in a team…