# Changing Magento theme based on referral URL

Tags: magento, themes

I'm a brand-new Magento developer, coming from more general web-dev.

What I'm trying to do is create a "Kiosk Mode" of a website to be displayed within an app. Kiosk mode is a stripped-down version of my existing Magento site for BROWSING only; no customer login, no cart. Don't show "Add to Cart" stuff on product pages, etc. I want the site to draw from my existing product catalogue. My site currently has three store-views, representing three different physical locations with different inventory (business is mainly local pickup).

From what I'm reading it seems like a Theme is the way to go here, but I've got a couple of questions:

1) Can I drive theme from referral URL? I've looked at this page, but the answer seems shaky and I don't want to dive in to the codebase on spec if I can help it:
[Change magento theme/storeview based on referring URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12519709/change-magento-theme-storeview-based-on-referring-url)

2) Does everything I'm describing above seem possible using Magento themes? Can I hide cart, change product page layout to remove "Add to Cart", etc?

Many thanks in advance!
Kim